# Ruling of raising hands in Du'a before Taslim

Tags: salat, fiqh, sunni, sunnah, shiism

Usually while making Du'a we raise hands.[image]

But right after Tashahud and Darood-e-Ibrahim in salah before we say "Assalamu Alaikum..." turning both sides (Taslim)

1. because even that is Du'a, why don't we raise our hands?
2. If some school of thought does it, which school of thought practice it?

Comment: I mostly think this is a style of the Shias. Is it true?

Comment: as much as I searched, i didn't find such a matter. perhaps some people do it since Darood is considered as a Dua... Otherwise at least it is not common between Shia...

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer Question 1 as for Q2 I don't even have the hint of an example or answer!

I think the answer for that is quite simple as we should/have to pray as the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) used to pray as he told us in many ahadith (hadiths) or at least many riwayas:

(Here quoted from [al adab -al mufrad](http://sunnah.com/adab/10/2))

> Abu Sulayman Malik ibn al-Huwayrith said,
>
> "We came to the
> Prophet, may  Allah bless him and grant him peace, being young men of
> a similar  age. We spent twenty nights with him. He thought that we
> desired our  own people and he asked us about those of our family we
> had left  behind, and we told him. He was merciful and kind, and said,
> 'Go back  to your family. Instruct and command them. **Pray as you have**
> **seen me  praying**. When it is time for the prayer, then let one of you
> give the  adhan and let the oldest of you lead the payer.;:

And Because it is in the prayer it has to follow the "rules" of the prayer. Or do you raise hands in a prayer while you are in sujud? We are approved to do dua' during sujud. Or do you raise hands in a prayer when you read some Verses which include a dua' as the last 2 verses in surat al-Baqara etc.?

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger
> of Allah (ﷺ) said, "A slave becomes nearest to his Rubb (Lord) when he is in
> prostration. So increase supplications in prostrations."
>
> [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/245)

Therefore it seems that nobody has narrated that the Prophet (may Allah bless him and grant him peace) ever did so. And this is not allowed according to [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/18522) (in Arabic).

On the other hand dua' isn't only a part of the prayer but also of the tawaf and sa'y and in both we are not asked to raise our hands! So raising hands for dua' isn't at all a standard, but it seems to be an established sunnah in cases and not in others.

Finally a [fatwa in Arabic](http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/18089/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1) making clear where and when raising up hands for dua' is permissible. For example it's also not sunnah to raise hands during the dua' of the imam in the middle of the speech of jumu'a unless the imam is asking for rain, as for during the prayer raising hands during the du'a isn't sunnah at the du'a of istiftah (at start of the prayer), the sujud and the tashahhud.
 See also [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/11543) which explicitly explains when one should raise his hands for dua' and when not.

And Allah knows best!